# Construct with straight edge a parallel to two lines.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

It is known that we can't with just a straight edge, given a line and a point out of the line in a plane to construct other line, passing through the point, parallel to the first. I know a proof of this fact lying on projective geometry.

However, I also know that is actually possible, with just a straight edge, given two parallel lines and a point out of both in a plane, construct a parallel to both lines and passing through the point. But I can't find neither the algorithm nor the demonstration of it.

Someone know how to do?

Comment: With *just a straight edge*?  Or are we allowed to use a compass as well?  If you are allowed to use a compass, are you familiar with how to construct a right angle?

Comment: Just a dry straight edge, nothing more. I barely remember the procediment...

Comment: Your title says to use a compass but your text says not. Which is it?

Comment: Wow, big mistake of mine. Without compass, I fixed the title.

Answer (score 5):

Idea: Constructuion is based on trapezoids

[image: The idea]